# Using the 'astar' function of OrientDB: an SQL call in Java

Tags: java, sql, orientdb, graph-databases, a-star

I'm using OrientDB to represent large city maps and calculate the shortest traversal times between a pair of nodes when the need arises. I have the following method:

```
public void getShortestPath(int from, int to){
    String query = "SELECT astar(?, ?, time, direction=OUT, customHeuristicFormula=EUCLIDEAN) FROM V";
    OResultSet set = db.query(query, getNode(from).getProperty("@rid"), getNode(to).getProperty("@rid"));
}
```

The `getNode(nodeID)` method returns the OVertex object present in the database, hence we can identify the `@rid`. Clearly, this method serves no purpose as is.

My issue comes when trying to call the `astar` query on the database (i.e. line two of the method). I'm getting the following error: `OCommandSQLParsingException: Error parsing query` upon reaching the first `(` (i.e. error encountering the open bracket). Removing the brackets entirely simply resulted in the same error occurring on the `#` in front of the first `@rid` value.

I can't seem to find any example of using this function in practice, and (at least I think) I'm using the function call as suggested by [the documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.1.x/sql/SQL-Functions.html#astar). Look forward to hearing your thoughts.

I'm using the most recent version of OrientDB: 3.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error had nothing to do with the bracket itself. Passing the `"direction='OUT'"` and `"customHeuristicFormula='EUCLIDEAN'"` parameters in as part of the string was the problem. The below block did the trick.

```
    String sql = "SELECT ASTAR(" + getNode(from).getProperty("@rid") + ", " + getNode(to).getProperty("@rid") + ", time) FROM V";
    try(OResultSet set = db.query(sql, "direction='OUT'", "customHeuristicFormula='EUCLIDEAN'")) {
         // some code...
    }
```